# Enable Ctrl+C for copy and Ctrl+Shift+C for interrupt

Tags: xterm

I would like to enable <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> for copy and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> for SIGINT/interrupt in xterm.

I have found the [following](https://askubuntu.com/questions/617629/how-to-enable-cut-or-copy-paste-in-xterm#answer-731130).

```
XTerm*VT100.Translations: #override \
      Shift Ctrl<Key>V: insert-selection(CLIPBOARD) \n\ 
      Shift Ctrl<Key>V: insert-selection(PRIMARY) \n\ 
      Shift<Btn1Down>: select-start() \n\ 
      Shift<Btn1Motion>: select-extend() \n\ 
      Shift<Btn1Up>: select-end(CLIPBOARD) \n\
```

which I believe is partially there but doesn't give a demonstrate how to override <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's "partially there", but runs into the problem that there is no predefined (single byte) character corresponding to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.  You need that single byte character for the interrupt (`intr`) setting with `stty`.  Likewise, control+V is the literal next (`lnext`) setting in `stty`.

You could use the translation resource to send a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> character using the `string` feature, e.g., something like these lines in a `translations` resource:

```
ctrl shift <key>C : string(0x03) \n\
ctrl shift <key>V : string(0x16) \n\
```

and then assign the unshifted keys (putting a tilde **`~`** before the `shift keyword).

From the followup comment, I agree that just specifying the **un**shifted pattern should be enough:

```
~Shift Ctrl <KeyPress> v: insert-selection(CLIPBOARD)\n\
~Shift Ctrl <KeyPress> c: copy-selection(CLIPBOARD)\n
```

a few notes (which might be documented, but the source code helps):

- `<KeyPress>` means the same as `<Key>`
- the modifiers (and `<KeyPress>`) are matched ignoring case.
- the parts on the right-side of **`:`** are case-sensitive.

Normally there is no translation done for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> with or without the shift-modifier.  xterm simply gets an `XKeyEvent` which has the modifier information and the character, and decodes *that*.  The `translations` resource alters the events which might be sent to xterm.

You would use modifiers in a translation to limit the matches, e.g., omitting <kbd>Shift</kbd> means it matches whether or not the shift-key is pressed.  Adding an explicit **`~shift`** (**no**shift) modifier has no effect on the match for **`shift`**.

Further reading:

- [Custom Key Bindings](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#h3-Custom-Key-Bindings) (xterm manual)

Comment: Do you mind posting a slightly more complete example for both Ctrl+C,Ctrl+Shift+C,Ctrl+V,Ctrl+Shift+V.  I am trying to accomplish the same thing as described and accomplished here http://askubuntu.com/questions/53688/making-ctrlc-copy-text-in-gnome-terminal except for xterm

Comment: So this appears to work `~Shift Ctrl <KeyPress> v: insert-selection(CLIPBOARD)\n\
 ~Shift Ctrl <KeyPress> c: copy-selection(CLIPBOARD)\n`  It appears there is no need to change the Ctrl+Shift+C and Ctrl+Shift+V because it does so automatically.

Comment: I have marked this as the accepted answer.  Thank you!  Is there a similar command that makes this work in `gnome-terminal` I'm try to find a way to select text over multiple pages which xterm doesn't seem to support http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/339411/autoscroll-when-selecting-text-xterm-scrollbar

Answer (score 3):

This appears to work in xterm

```
xterm -xrm 'XTerm*VT100.Translations: #override\n\
 ~Shift <KeyPress> Prior: scroll-back(1,halfpage)\n\
 ~Shift <KeyPress> Next:  scroll-forw(1,halfpage)\n\
  Shift <KeyPress> Prior: string(0x1b)string("[5~")\n\
  Shift <KeyPress> Next:  string(0x1b)string("[6~")\n\
 ~Shift Ctrl <KeyPress> v: insert-selection(CLIPBOARD)\n\
 ~Shift Ctrl <KeyPress> c: copy-selection(CLIPBOARD)\n
'
```