# Autoscroll when selecting text xterm scrollbar

Tags: xterm

So I do something like the following

```
cat testfile
```

Now text has spanned multiple lines.

I could do PgUp+Shift to go up but how do I select such text while moving up?  I have the scrollbar enabled like so.

```
xterm -xrm 'xterm*ScrollBar: on
*XTerm*scrollBar: true
Xterm*rightScrollBar: false
Xterm*multiScroll: on
Xterm*jumpScroll: on'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That would be *dragging*, which xterm doesn't do.  Rather than that, you could (using the scrollbar or wheel-mouse, etc), scroll up and use the right-mouse-button to *extend* a selection.

Further reading:

- [Making large selections in xterm (and urxvt and Gnome Terminal)](https://utcc.utoronto.ca/~cks/space/blog/unix/XTermLargeSelections)