# C SIGINT signal in Linux

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, sigint

I want to make a specific combination of keyboard keys in order to terminate a process e.x I want to terminate the process by pressin CTRL + C ^ 3 (pressing three times C: CTRL +CCC).

So basically I want to replace CTRL + C with CTRL + CCC

Comment: Trap that signal and do counting by yourself

Comment: How to trap it, i can't figure it out ?

Comment: check man pages for signal(7) and sigaction, set a handler for SIGINT and count inside the handler.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The default behavior of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is a combination of two things. The terminal driver¹ does not transmit this key press, but instead sends a [SIGINT signal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_(IPC)#POSIX_signals) to the foreground process². By default, a process dies when it receives a SIGINT, but the process can set a signal handler, and then it'll run the signal handler when it receives SIGINT.

There's no way to configure the terminal driver to only convert the third <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in a row to kill the foreground process. To do that, you need to count to three in your program. There are two ways you can do that, which will behave differently if the user presses something else between the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>'s.

One way is to disable <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>'s behavior of sending a signal and telling the terminal driver to instead pass it through. You can do that by calling [`stty intr \^-`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stty.1.html) from a shell script or [`tcsetattr(fd, &termios)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/tcsetattr.3.html) with `termios.c_cc[VINTR]` set to `_POSIX_VDISABLE` from C. Then, in your program's input processing loop, exit when you've seen three <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>'s in a row.

The other way is to set a signal handler for SIGINT that counts how many times it's been invoked and terminates the program the third time. You may want to reset the counter if there's normal input in between.

¹  <sub>Not the terminal emulator, the generic part of the operating system that handles all terminals.</sub> 
²  <sub>I'm only explaining the simple case. This is not a treatise on how the terminal driver works.</sub>

Comment: Can you briefly give me an example for second way ?

Comment: @AlbionShala You never said what programming language you're using. And anyway programming is off-topic here when it goes beyond simple scripting. But a web search with the name of your programming language and "signal handler" and "tutorial" should give you examples.

Comment: Actually yes i mentioned that i am using C in Linux but it was editted, anyhow thanks a lot, i really appreciate it

Comment: `IGNBRK` has nothing to do with Ctrl-C being translated to `SIGINT`. It's `ISIG` in `c_lflag` who is controlling that (also `c_cc[VINTR]` can be set to 0 to disable it, or to another char). `stty -intr` is **not** a valid command. A `VINTR`/Ctrl-C won't send a signal to the "foreground process", but to the foreground *process group* (job), ie. when running `a|b|c` and pressing ^C, a signal will be sent to the  `a`, `b` and `c` processes.

Comment: @mosvy Thanks, I hadn't done that in a while and I should have spent more than 5s re-reading the man page. Regarding process groups, see footnote 2.

Comment: @AlbionShala But the fact that a `SIGINT` will be sent to all the processes in the group is **essential**, because it makes clear the dangerous futility of setting up a `SIGINT` handler as a way of key-binding; if the program is run as part of a pipeline or through a wrapper, it will still be (indirectly) killed by the 1st ^C (it will get a `SIGPIPE` when trying to write to the pipe, or have its children summarily killed while it's still counting up to 3). And changing tty attributes is no better, unless it's a full screen app (like `vi` or `emacs`) which has the tty all to itself.

Answer (score 5):

You can't change key binding in your code because a signal is a software generated interrupt that is sent to a process by the OS. when user press ctrl-c another process tell something to your process.

There are fix set of signals that can be sent to a process.
signals are similar to interrupts, the difference being that interrupts are mediated by the processor and handled by the kernel while signals are mediated by the kernel (possibly via system calls) and handled by processes. The kernel may pass an interrupt as a signal to the process that caused it (typical examples are SIGSEGV, SIGBUS, SIGILL and SIGFPE).

you can remap signal key binding in your computer with stty

[Enable Ctrl+C for copy and Ctrl+Shift+C for interrput](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/339160/enable-ctrlc-for-copy-and-ctrlshiftc-for-interrput)

https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix3/upt/ch05_08.htm

if you want exactly 3 times ctrl-c. you can count SIGINT and break the program when 3 times ctrl-c pressed. (pressing three times C: CTRL +CCC).

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<signal.h>
#include<unistd.h>

void sig_handler(int signo)
{
    static int counter=0;
    if (signo == SIGINT)
        counter++;
    printf("received SIGINT %d times\n", counter);
    if (counter == 3)
        exit(0);
}

int main() 
{ 
    if (signal(SIGINT, sig_handler) == SIG_ERR)
        printf("\ncan't catch SIGINT\n");
    while(1) 
        sleep(1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What happens if I want to terminate with `CTRL + AAA` instead of `CTRL + CCC`?

Comment: Changing key binding in your code is not possible as far as i know. but like i said you can change signal key binding in stty  and in your terminal emulator.

Comment: you [do not use](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html) `printf` and `exit` in signal handlers, ever. just think what happens if a `SIGINT` is coming while the program is running another printf or flushing the stdio buffers, or within a handler registered with atexit(3).

Comment: @AbhikBose You can easily change the keybinding from Ctrl-C to Ctrl-A with `stty intr '^A'` (from C you do that with tcsetattr(), look up the termios(3) manpage).

Comment: Thanks @mosvy but this is a proof of concept code not a real one. why you don't add an answer and explain us more about what you know. because i didn't get what you said in your last comment.

Comment: @RasoolZiafaty *just because* it's a proof of concept it should be correct. Besides, doing it correctly will make it shorter and simpler, not the reverse. Notice that the use of `signal()` instead of `sigaction()` is also highly dubious: on some systems, `signal(3)` will set the handler as with `SA_RESETHAND` ie the handler  will be *disabled* after the first ^C.

Comment: I tried this but actually the program stops at the very first C i press still like in default mode, i press CTRL +C and it stops