# xterm translations ignoring "Shift" specifier

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, xterm, x-resources

I'd like to change the key mappings for XTerm so that <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> is copying from the clipboard, but <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> is still `SIGINT`, as is the default.  Basically, I want to do the same thing as [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/339160), but with the opposite mapping.  Likewise, I want <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> to paste from the clipboard and leave <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> unchanged.

This seems straightforward enough after looking at the answers to that question and at the XTerm manual.  I just want to translate the *shifted* versions of these key combinations.  So I tried the following and several variations on it:

```
XTerm*VT100.translations: #override \n\
    Shift Ctrl <Key> c: copy-selection(CLIPBOARD) \n\
    Shift Ctrl <Key> v: insert-selection(CLIPBOARD)
```

However, the effect of this is the opposite of what I want.  <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> is now copy and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> is `SIGINT`.  In light of the question I linked above, the simplest way to interpret this is just that XTerm is treating my `Shift` as `~Shift` or something along those lines, but this seems unlikely.  Am I missing something obvious here?

My understanding is that XTerm translates the keyboard input before it reaches `stty`, so I don't see an obvious way to blame it on that either.  Please correct me if this is wrong.

Comment: It's *X Toolkit* that does the work, and just the setting shown won't cause this. You might have other translations resource settings, xmodmap settings or even an incorrect keyboard type.

Comment: @ThomasDicky Thanks.  Can you point me to any resources on how to diagnose the problem?

Comment: Note that other translations are probably not the problem.  My Xresources and Xdefaults files don't have any other translation settings that are related at all to CTRL-C, etc.